# How to identify why this code still calls itself even when no is selected but only after the the input was initially a yes

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

When the code is run for the first time and a user input is requested, entering 'N' terminates the code and this is ok.  But if 'y' is entered, when it loops over and asks the question again and 'n' is entered, it still loops over.

```
def call():
    i=0
    while i<2:
        print('i am a function that calls myself')
        i +=1
    
    a = input('y or n: ').lower()
    while a == 'y':
        call()
    print('this is the end')

call()
```

I tried using a debugger and it appears this is not a syntax problem but some other error.

Comment: Your code only tries to ask the user for an input once - you need to call input again to ask the user again, from within the loop itself, or `a` will never get updated. Please try doing so, and if it doesn't work or you get stuck, [edit] your post to indicate that.

Comment: @nanofarad you are absolutely right.  Thank you.

Comment: @nanofarad I was able to fix it by making variable 'a' a global variable and so the changes would update the value of 'a' globally.

Comment: @Udemezue just so you know, that is generally considered a bad practice and should be avoided outside of anything but the smallest programs